# Relation between complements, $p$-complements and $\pi$-complements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group, a few definitions:

1) If $H \le G$, then a *complement* of $H$ in $G$ is a subgroup $K \le G$ such that 
$$
 G = HK \quad \mbox{and} \quad H \cap K = \{ 1 \}.
$$

2) Let $p$ a prime number, then a $p$-complement is a subgroup $K \le G$ such that 
    its index $|G : K|$ is the highest $p$-power dividing $|G|$.

3) Let $\pi$ be a set of primes, a subgroup $K \le G$ is called a $\pi$-complement if
    $|K|$ is not divisible by any prime in $\pi$, and every prime divisor of its index $|G : K|$ lies in $\pi$.

Definition 1) seems quite natural to me, here complement is defined with respect to $G$ and a subgroup $H$, in the other cases I am wondering if there are also subgroups such that the complement relates to them like in 1).

For example for 2) if I have a $p$-complement, then there exist a Sylow-$p$-subgroup $P$ such that $P \cap K = \{ 1 \}$ (by order arguments) and also we must have $KP = G$ by considering the size of $KP$.

But if I have a Sylow-$p$-subgroup, then there does not need to exists a subgroup $K \le G$ such that $P \cap K = \{1\}$ and $PK = G$. So I think the notion of $p$-complement generalises the notion of complement with respect to a subgroup, right? Because every $p$-complement is also a complement in the sense of 1) with respect to some Sylow-$p$-subgroup, which is guaranteed by the Sylow-Theorems.

For 3), this obviously generalises 2). But under what circumstances can we find to a $\pi$-complement $K$ in $G$ a subgroup $H \le G$ such that 1) is fullfilled, namely such that
$$
 G = HK \quad \mbox{and} \quad H \cap K = \{ 1 \}?
$$

I know one case, if $K$ is normal then by Schur-Zassenhaus we can find such an $H$, but guess there could be anything more said about that.

Comment: By your argument, I would say that $p$-complement specializes the definition of complement, since every $p$-complement (when they exist) is a complement, but not vice versa.  Similarly, $\pi$-complement specializes $p$-complement to an even more special/rare/included condition.

Comment: In finite solvable groups, there are $\pi$-complements for every set of primes, known as Hall $\pi^{\prime}$-subgroups, after P.Hall. In simple groups, $\pi$-complements are relatively rare, unless $\pi = p^{\prime}$ for some prime $p.$

Comment: @EricTowers: You are right! Every $p$-complement is a complement for some Sylow-$p$-subgroup, so they specialize complements. But $\pi$-complements really generalise $p$-complements, because every $p$-complement is a $\pi$-complement for $\pi = \{ p \}$.  So complement and $\pi$-complement both generalise the notion of $p$-complement, and now I am asking about the relation between both generalisations.

Comment: @Stefan:  You also are right!  I managed to turn myself around when writing about the $\pi$-complement and asserted backwards.  Sorry.

Comment: Could the Frattini Argument employed for finding complements?